# when time shifted awgn signal added, why in frquency domain sample changing the amplitude

Tags: fft

I am trying to run below matlab code, but resulted varying samples. why is such behaviour? what made to curved nature of plot?

```
K>> abcd = awgn(zeros(61441,1),60);
K>> def = abcd(1:end-1)+abcd(2:end);
K>> plot(fftshift(real(fft(def))))
```

[image: FFT of awgn noise]

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do, what the expected outcome is, why you have this expectation and how the result that you are getting is different from what you think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP is delaying by one sample and adding the two waveforms together. The delay and add by one sample would have a low pass response which would be consistent with the spectrum shown if the left and right most samples represents the spectrum near $f_s/2$ and the middle samples are in proximity of DC where $f_s$ is the sampling rate. (Which matches the code given using the FFTSHIFT function). This is exactly the expected response for the transfer function given by:

$$H(z)=1+z^{-1}$$

This is intuitive when you consider that the lowest frequency components in the white noise would add given very little phase shift of those frequency components from one sample to the next (they will be in phase) while the highest frequency components would have a delay causing 180° of phase shift and therefore cancellation. If the two were subtracted instead of adding we would see a complementary high pass response.

What is also interesting in this operation is if you continue to then decimate by taking every other sample, the decimation aliasing would be that which would restore the white noise property of the random signal given by every other sample in time of the above waveform.